# drag in nscollectionview crashing

Tags: objective-c, nscollectionview

I have an NSCollectionView displaying images stored internally (ie-not files). The collection is displaying correctly. However, when I start a drag operation, the app crashes. It crashes before the drag ever leaves the collection view. I am returning an internal image for the drag image. The crash log shows that the crash occurs in the drag code. I must be missing something but I cannot find it. My code is based on Apple's sample.

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView canDragItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSSet<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths withEvent:(NSEvent *)event
{
    if (indexPaths != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"1.0");
        return YES;
    }
    else
        return NO;
}

- (id <NSPasteboardWriting>)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView pasteboardWriterForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"2");
    NSURL   *testImageURL;
    NSBundle* myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString* myImagePath = [myBundle pathForResource:@"blue-bridge" ofType:@"png"];
    testImageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myImagePath];
    //NSURL *anurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/sysadmin/Downloads/wonderwoman.jpg"] ;

    return testImageURL ;
}
```

pasteboardWriterForItemAtIndexPath is being called and then the app crashes with;

[image: crash log]

I have tried different images, both internal and external, png and jpeg, so the image itself doesn't seem be the problem.

Suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to avoid paths, use urls.

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me is that you're returning an `URL` object from `-collectionView:pasteboardWriterForItemAtIndexPath:`. The returned value is expected to be `id<NSPasteboardWriting>` and `URL` does not adopt `NSPasteboardWriting`. You might consider turning your URL into an `NSImage` or something more pasteboard-friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My code is copied from apple's sample code and it says "Some kinds of model objects (for example, NSURL) are themselves suitable pasteboard writers." and this is also in the NSURL doc. However, I tried an image instead and it still fails. Also, the stack shows the crash is in exactly the same place as with a URL.

Comment: I have discovered that when I include jpeg as a pasteboard type, the drag no longer crashes. But no drag image is drawn either, and none of the other drag methods are called.

Answer (score 3):

From the stack trace I'd say it's crashing when trying to generate the dragging image. To make sure that's the case implement [-collectionView:draggingImageForItemsAtIndexwithEvent:offset:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionviewdelegate/1528175-collectionview?language=objc) and return any image, such as one of the system ones: `[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameFolder]`

If that doesn't crash then you know for sure the problem is with your NSCollectionViewItem and how it's drawing its UI. Share that code so and we can probably help you.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I implemented draggingImage... but it never gets called. I'm not sure why this is. I removed pasteboardWriterForItemAtIndexPath... but it didn't help. The docs seem to say that one *or* the other is needed, but it never gets called. Still looking at this option.

Comment: Could you produce a simple test project of this happening?